# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Tags: html, arrays, angular, typescript, foreach

Im working on a project that I want to display and edit a array. My problem is 'Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined' I don't understand why.

My component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="editHomeboxPForm" (ngSubmit)="onEditHomeboxP()" class="col s12" materialize>

           <div class="row">
               <div class="input-field col s10">
                 <div formArrayName="sensors_id">
                   <div class="form-group" *ngFor="let sensor of editHomeboxPForm.get('sensors_id').value; let i = index">
                     <br>
                     <select formControlName="{{i}}" id="sensors_id" materialize="material_select"
     [materializeSelectOptions]="homeboxp.sensors" [ngClass]="{invalid:
     invalidinput}">
                       <option value="" disabled selected>Select Sensor</option>
                       <option *ngFor="let sensor of homeboxp.sensors" [value]="sensor.sensors_id">{{sensor.sensor_serial}}</option>
                     </select>
                     <div class="button-left">
                       <button *ngIf="editHomeboxPForm.controls.sensors_id.value.length > 1" type="button" class="fa"
     (click)="onRemoveItem(i)">RemoveSensor</button>
                     </div>
                   </div>
                 </div>

               </div>
               <div class="input-field col s2">
               <button type="button" class="btn" (click)="onAddItem()">AddSensor</button>
               </div>
          </div>
</form>
```

Component.ts

```
  editHomeboxPForm: FormGroup;
  homeboxp: HomeboxP;

  constructor(private hps: HomeboxpackageService,
    private router: Router,
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {

      this.editHomeboxPForm = new FormGroup({
      'serial_number': new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.nullValidator]),
      'sensors_id': this.fb.array([]) 
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.populateFormHomeboxP();

  }
  ngAfterViewChecked() {

    Materialize.updateTextFields();
  }
  populateFormHomeboxP() {
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(
      params => {
        this.hps.getHomeboxPById(params['id']).subscribe(
          homeboxp => {
            this.homeboxp = homeboxp;
            this.editHomeboxPForm.controls['serial_number'].setValue(homeboxp.serial_number);
            this.editHomeboxPForm.controls['sensors_id'].setValue(homeboxp.sensors_id); // at SafeSubscriber.eval [as _next]
           }
        );
      }
    );
  }
  onEditHomeboxP() {
    this.loading = true;
    let editHomeboxP = new HomeboxP(
      this.editHomeboxPForm.value
    );
    editHomeboxP.homebox_id = this.homeboxp.homebox_id;
    this.hps.UpdateHomeboxp(editHomeboxP).subscribe(
      result => {
        if (result === true) {
          Materialize.toast('successfully', 4000);
                 } else {
          this.loading = false;
        }
      },
      error => {
        this.loading = false;
      }
    );
  }
  onAddItem() {
    (<FormArray>this.editHomeboxPForm.controls['sensors_id']).push(new FormControl('', Validators.required));
   }
   onRemoveItem(index: number) {
    (<FormArray>this.editHomeboxPForm.controls['sensors_id']).removeAt(index);
 }
```

Can you suggest me, how is the problem. In console: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined. Also in console display all json. Like this:

> {"StatusCode":0,"StatusMessage":"OK","StatusDescription":{ "sensors":
>   [ {"sensor_serial":"SensorSerial1", "sensors_id":"11E807676E3F30B5"},
>   {"sensor_serial":"sensorserial2", "sensors_id":"11E807679D82841L"},
>   {"sensor_serial":"sensorserial3", "sensors_id":"11E80767A5CD2820"} ]
>   ,"homeboxpackage_id":"11E80768K", "active":0,
>   "homebox_id":"11E8076792BD0164J",
>   "date_created":"2018-02-01T15:55:54.000Z", "date_modified":null,
>   "serial_number":"serialn1", "user_id":"3"} }

Comment: Can you provide a working fiddle? Or at least the complete error stack? In which file/line does the error occure?

Comment: this.editHomeboxPForm.controls['sensors_id'].setValue(homeboxp.sensors_id); // at SafeSubscriber.eval [as _next]

Comment: Reading the docs of FormArray (https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray#setValue) I saw that the value of `setValue()` has to be of type array. So maybe just wrap your value in an array like this: `this.editHomeboxPForm.controls['sensors_id'].setValue([homeboxp.sensors_id]);`

Comment: I suggest using the debugger built into your browser to determine where the error is occurring. All of them have the ability to break on exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can gather looking at template, the data in the `homeboxp` variable is actually the array `sensors` from your response. You want to iterate the array `sensors` and from each object in that array push the `sensor_id` to the formarray:

```
// iterate array, grab the sensor.id and push it to form array
this.homeboxp.sensors.forEach(x => {
  (this.editHomeboxPForm.get('sensors_id') as FormArray)
    .push(new FormControl(x.sensors_id))
})
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ejrfpu?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)**